# Class '..\Unit\UnitTestCase' not found

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel-5, phpunit

I am upgrading `laravel` from `5.5.*` to `5.6.0`. Composer install ran fine. I am trying to run unit tests upon which this error is popping up.

> Class '..\Unit\UnitTestCase' not found

This is the stack trace of the error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'PhiraterTest\Unit\UnitTestCase'
> not found in
> /home/vagrant/code/phirater-l51/tests/unit/Phirater/AdditionalCurrencies/CreateAdditionalCurrencyCommandHandlerTest.php:11
> Stack trace:
> #0 /home/vagrant/code/phirater-l51/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/Fileloader.php(64):
> include_once()
> #1 /home/vagrant/code/phirater-l51/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/Fileloader.php(48):
> PHPUnit\Util\Fileloader::load('/home/vagrant/c...')
> #2 /home/vagrant/code/phirater-l51/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestSuite.php(325):
> PHPUnit\Util\Fileloader::checkAndLoad('/home/vagrant/c...')
> #3 /home/vagrant/code/phirater-l51/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestSuite.php(403):
> PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite->addTestFile('/home/vagrant/c...')
> #4 /home/vagrant/code/phirater-l51/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Runner/BaseTestRunner.php(65):
> PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite->addTestFiles(Array)
> #5 /home/vagrant/code/phirater-l51/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/Command.php(169):
> PHPUnit\Runner\BaseTestRunner->getTest('tes in
> /home/vagrant/code/phirater-l51/tests/unit/Phirater/AdditionalCurrencies/CreateAdditionalCurrencyCommandHandlerTest.php
> on line 11

My unit tests are in `tests/` directory. My `UnitTestCase` class in extended by `\TestCase` class and `TestCase` class is extended by `BrowserKitTestCase`. What am i doing wrong here? What could be the solution?

Comment: Run `composer dump-autoload` and It would be fixed.

Comment: @STA already done that!

Comment: Have you added in composer 
`"autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    }`

Comment: take a look here :
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/php-fatal-error-class-testcase-not-found

Comment: @AnkitJindal yes I have

Comment: Does [this](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/testing/class-teststestcase-not-found-when-attempting-to-run-test?page=1#reply=370757) help?

Answer (score 1):

If your dependency class is really present and has proper namespace, then the most probable reasons of mentioned error are (avoid copying below examples to your project, that will definetely not work):

- **composer.json** file (root directory) has no relevant record of the dependency (do not forget *composer.lock* file also), smth like:

  ```
  "autoload-dev": {
      "psr-4": {
          "Tests\\": "tests/"
      }
  },
  ```
- as a result of above, **vendor/autoload.php** file (or any of its merged siblings, e.g. *vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php*, depending on your case) can miss relevant record of the dependency, smth like:

  ```
    return array(
        'PHPUnit\\Framework\\TestCase' => '/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestCase.php',
  ```

In most such cases it is really a missed dependency delivered by **autoload.php** functionality, which in its turn caused by *composer* malfunctioning. So taking in account all that, try to update *composer* itself by running `composer self-update`, and then updating your dependencies by `composer update`.